# Generic Absoluteness restricted to formulas with low complexity or to the class of forcings

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Ikegami and Schlicht proposed a principle, namely generic absoluteness, which is stated below using Hamkins' and Lowe's terminology:

Working in $ZF$:

(Generic Absoluteness): For all formulas in language of set theory

$$\diamondsuit\Phi\longrightarrow\Phi$$

Which means if something is forceable then is already true.

This principle is false as Woodin gave the following counterexample:

$$\psi\equiv~~~\forall A\subseteq \omega_1~~\text{there exists a random real over}~ L[A]$$

In the sense that both $\Psi$ and $\neg \Psi$ are forceable over $ZF$.

I am not sure about the complexity of $\Psi$, but it seems it is $\Pi_3$.

> Now my questions are:

1) Is it consistent to have generic absoluteness restricted to formulas with complexity less than $\Pi_3$, or more precisely less than complexity of $\Psi$?

> > 2) Is there any nontrivial reasonable class of forcing notions avoiding a counter example?

For example, as suggested by Schlicht:

> > Is there a model of $ZF$ such that generic absoluteness holds for adding arbitrary many Cohen reals?

---

Edit: The first problem is solved by Joel's answer.

Comment: Your sentence $\psi$ is a local property (see http://jdh.hamkins.org/local-properties-in-set-theory/), since we can check whether or not it is true by looking inside $V_{\omega+5}$ or so. So it has complexity $\Delta_2$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Thank you. so now the question is meaningless.

Comment: Perhaps I should post my comment as an answer?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins It's good idea to post your comment as an answer. I modified my question because actually I had it in my mind but I posted only one of them.

Comment: OK, I posted an answer, and explained the positive result for $\Sigma_1$.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the second question? On one reading of it, if the class avoids counterexamples, then of course the principle is true for that class, since that what it means to avoid counterexamples.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I made a correction

Comment: To clarify your second question, are you asking about the consistency of ZF + statements like "generic absoluteness for c.c.c. forcings"?

Comment: @NoahSchweber yes, something like this.

Comment: For Schlicht's question at the end, here is a proposed negative answer:  Start in any model of ZF, and then add $\aleph_\alpha$ many Cohen reals, where $\alpha$ is very large. In the resulting forcing extension $V[G]$, there is an $\aleph_\alpha$ sequence of distinct reals, constructed directly from $G$, but it seems to me that there will be no $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$-sequence (this is clear in ZFC, and I think one can prove it also in ZF).  So $\alpha$ is definable in $V[G]$. This contradicts $\Diamond\varphi\to\varphi$ in $V$, since we can make $\alpha$ either even or odd.

Comment: If that proof idea works, then it would be an alternative proof to Woodin's refutation of the main principle.

Answer (score 6):

Your sentence $\psi$ is a local property (see my blog post [Local properties in set theory](http://jdh.hamkins.org/local-properties-in-set-theory)), since we can check whether or not it is true by looking inside $V_{\omega+5}$ or so. So it has complexity $\Delta_2$. So one cannot have the principle for assertions at that level of complexity.

Meanwhile, if one goes down to $\Sigma_1$, then the axiom $\Diamond\varphi\to\varphi$ for sentences $\varphi$ is consistent with ZFC, since it follows from the maximality principle, which asserts $\Diamond\square\varphi\to\varphi$, since every forceable $\Sigma_1$ statement is automatically forceably necessary, since once it becomerue it remains true in all further extensions. My article

- J. D. Hamkins, [A simple maximality principle](http://jdh.hamkins.org/maximalityprinciple/), J. Symbolic Logic, vol. 68, iss. 2, pp. 527-550, 2003.

explains why MP is relatively consistent with ZFC, and with a little strength, you can also allow real parameters.

In the case of $\Pi_1$ assertions $\varphi$, the implication $\Diamond\varphi\to\varphi$ is simply provable in ZF, since if a universal statement holds in some extension, then it is already true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but what about the second question?

Comment: The last sentence implies that whenever $\Diamond\varphi\to\varphi$ holds for all $\Sigma_1$ sentences $\varphi$, it also holds for all Boolean combinations of $\Sigma_1$ sentences (by considering the DNF). Thus, the latter principle is also consistent with ZFC.